# Locking Entire DB - Real World Example?

Tags: sql-server, locking

Is there a practical real-world example where SQL server would lock the entire DB? I see from this page, that it is possible for the DB engine to lock the entire DB: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189849(v=sql.105).aspx

But would this ever happen in practice, or is it just an edge case for someone doing something very specialised?

Comment: Perhaps some dbcc commands. Or restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Exclusive lock on a database for

- restoring database
- renaming database
- altering database /set read_only/ set single_user/ set
  read_committed_snapshot on